# Load byte format to bitmap and store in cache to load in listview for smooth scrolling in android

Tags: android

I am working on requirement of loading images to custom list view in android. I am getting the data from server in bytes format.

While loading that data to list view and display its missing smooth scrolling. Can any please help me to come out of this problem and how to cache this images to increase the performance?

Comment: If you show us some code, we'll be glad to help you work out your issue.

Comment: You can use image loader library. For ex universal image loader, picasso.